# Using a for loop to calculate a meal price based on a range of tip percentages

Tags: python, loops

I'm going back and forth and screwing myself up on this code. I have a formula to calculate total meal price.

```
def total_cost(price,tax,tip):

    bill = price+(price*tax)+((price+(price*tax))*tip)
    return bill

new_bill = total_cost(15,.08875,.18)

print(new_bill)
```

From there, how do I write a for loop that computes the total price of a meal, for different tipping rates, starting from 15% and ending at 25% (both inclusive) at 1% increments?

Comment: Why was the code removed?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to loop over the percentages:

```
for tip in range(15, 26, 1):  # the end point is exclusive with "range"
    cost = total_cost(15, 0.08875, tip/100.)  # in python3 you could use tip/100
    print(cost)
```

Answer (score 1):

Super simplified, but this would be a first pass:

```
tips = list(range(15, 26))

for tip in tips:
    print("For " + str(tip) + "% the total cost is $" + str(total_cost(price, tax, tip/100))
```

Or the for loop could be:

```
for tip in range(15, 26, 1):
```

...to save a tiny bit of memory.

Comment: Are you sure `range(0.15, 0.26, 0.01)` doesn't throw a `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.`? It does so on my computer.

Comment: Yeah, range is integer only.  First passes are prone to wishing certain things work certain ways.

Comment: I totally agree with "wishing certain things work certain ways"! :)

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

```
print list(total_cost(15, 0.08875, tip / 100.) for tip in range(15, 26))
```

The part in the outermost parenthesis is a *generator* - *it does nothing itself* as it is only an *algorithm*.

The function `list()` forces it to work.